# How to rename a node in D3 graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rename, icicle-diagram

I need to provide "renaming" functionality to rename nodes using the Icicle example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4347473).

I am not able to find any solutions similar to what I would like to do, and as browsers usually do not allow for right click, I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to allow for this option and then also how to go about allowing someone to be able to rename a specific node's name.

Thanks.

Comment: Make each node selectable and show a textfield next to the graph that allows to change the node's name?

Comment: If you google for editable text in D3 you will find some interesting links. There are some buggy implementations but this [one](http://jsbin.com/adUnIwuH/8/edit) seems to offer a workable path (click on text to see it in action), including instructions to push changes to server, if desired.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. And many thanks @FernOfTheAndes, that example is good! Will have a look at using it.

Comment: Hi @FernOfTheAndes, I used the on click part of the example you provided, but I am a little confused about some of the lines in that function. I am using rects and labels, how would I update the nodes data without having actual "nodes" as in that example? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user2651192, would you care to put a minimal jsfiddle together? It would make it easier to work together on this.

Comment: Hi @FernOfTheAndes, I think that it is updating the nodes data, but my bootstrap popover that I have - it is not updating in the heading. Nothing to do with D3, so if you would like to post your comment as an answer I will accept it as the answer for this question because that is the example I used. Thanks!

Comment: @user2651192 Agree, it is good to put a workable solution in the records. Thanks.

Comment: @user2651192 How are you coming along on this issue?

Comment: Hi @FernOfTheAndes, it is working well. I have had to move on to other D3 tasks for what I am doing - but I will finalize this by the end of the week and let you know. The example you posted works quite quick and immediately changes the label, the only thing I may need (that I can think of now) is to change the prompt to a text field that is displayed near to the selected node and I am not yet sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record and per kind request by user2651192, the most workable path for this that we could find is [here](http://jsbin.com/adUnIwuH/8/edit) and, more specifically, the code to change the text is:

```
...
node.append("text")
    .text(function(d){ return d.name; })
    .on('click', function(d){
        var result = prompt('Change the name of the node',d.name);
        if(result) {
            d.name = result; 
            var node1 = canvas.selectAll('.node').data(nodes);
            node1.select('text')
                .text(function(d){ return d.name; });
        }
    )};
...
```